# How to get the stroke's color same goes with the fill's

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, stroke

So i've run into some similar questions but still can't find the right answer.

[image: THE PROBLEM]

I made a circle in Adobe Illustrator and stroke it with artistic brush but it turn out like that. I've tried to copy the fill's color code and paste it - didn't work. Saved the fill's color to color swatch and choose it to color the stroke - didn't work either.

Can anybody help me i'm so desperate :'D

ps: pardon my english.

Comment: So you want to fill the entire object with the same color as seen in the middle?

Comment: Use a Global Color for both stroke and fill

Answer (score 1):

It may be that your art brush has a colorization method that's causing it to be a different tone than the fill.

You can look into this by opening your brushes pallette and double-clicking the brush that you have applied to the shape.

[image]